# Output form builder as array to php file

Tags: javascript, php, formbuilder

Found this really cool form builder, https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder, and can see the data going to console, but what would I need to do to get the data in an array going to a php file?

Answer (score 0):

Put something usefull like an AJAX call to your php in between these lines
(just from their docu):

```
builder.on('save', function(payload){
  // submit the form or call an AJAX function here
});
```